# Creating Directory PHP / Wordpress Mkdir

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to a create a folder in the root of my website under

```
$root /docs/
```

my code looks at the current logged in user,
And see what country they are from.

Everyone has a country assigned to there account.

```js
    <?php
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $key = 'location';
  $single = true;
  $count = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );
  // echo $count   // this would result in something like...  '   america   '


  //some code i found on stackoverflow but im unsure of basedir? i dont understand it
  $path = ABSPATH;
  $upload_dir = $path['basedir'];
  $upload_dir = $upload_dir . '/docs/'.$count.'';
  if (! is_dir($upload_dir)) {
  mkdir( $upload_dir, 0755 );
  }
                
  // im using if(! because if there is a folder existing. then just skip.
```

**UPDATED** working ~!

```js
<?php
      $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
      $user_id = get_current_user_id();
      $key = 'location';
      $single = true;
      $count = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );

                                                $path = ABSPATH;
                                                $upload =  $path . 'docs/'.$count.'';
                                                 if (! is_dir($upload)) {
                                                 echo "made folder";
                                                 mkdir( $upload, 0755 ,true);
                                                 }
```

this folder is not in WP-content
this folder /docs/ is in the root directory of my Wordpress install.

Comment: Should i be using 

ABSPATH;
instead of get_home_path();

As i assume this is pointing to my homepath of my theme...

Answer (score 0):

Updated first post,
If anyone has access to close this thread please do :)

i fixed the issue by adding ,true
removing

```
$upload_dir = $path['basedir'];
```

as abspath; is the basedir,
removing the following / before docs as it would be htdocs//docs < broken linkage

and i set docs to 755 so that wordpress could add folders to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your upload dir should be like below, as ABSPATH is not an array:

$upload_dir = ABSPATH . '/docs/'.$count;

Assuming your count always has value, if unsure - use a conditional check before.